# Database of canceled flights

Tags: data-request, public-transport, aviation

I am looking for a table of flights that have been canceled.
For each canceled flight I need:

- Date and time at which departure had been expected. Example: `2017-08-25T19:20:00Z`
- Departure airport. Example: `KIX`
- Destination airport. Example: `OKA`
- (optional) airline company. Example: `JAL`
- (optional) flight number. Example: `JAL909`
- (optional) cancellation reason. Example: `weather`

The more open the better, but I am OK with not-so-open databases too.
Ten years of data would be ideal, but I am OK with one year of data too.
Worldwide would be ideal, but I am particularly interested in Japan/JAL data.

---

*Context: In Japan, flights get canceled whenever a typhoon comes close by, which happens every few weeks. Using past weather data and current weather forecast, I want to predict what flights will probably get canceled. JAL only provides [data](https://www.jal.co.jp/flight-status/dom/?FsBtn=route&DPORT=HND&APORT=OKA&DATEFLG=2) going back to the day before.*